# Gatsby mappings between Markdown node and TMDB nodes not working anymore

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have just upgraded a project from V2 to V4.8 and a simple mapping that I have in my Gatsby-config doesn't seem to be working anymore. The nodes are being created but any queries are just returning 'null' on the linked field. Here's my mapping in gatsby-config.js:

```
 mapping: {
    'MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.tmdb': `TmdbAccountWatchlistMovies.tmdbId`
  },
```

The relationship looks like it is being created in graphql:
[image: query showing linkage]

But, the query just returns null for any of the linked fields:
[image]

Anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `@link` GraphQL directive? (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/#foreign-key-fields)

Comment: Hmm where would I include that directive? Looks like something like this: 

`type MarkdownRemark implements Node {
  frontmatter: Frontmatter
}

type Frontmatter {
  tmdb: [tmdbAccountWatchlistMovies] @link(by: "tmdbId")
}
`

Would that go in my gatsby-node.js?

Comment: Okay, @link is promising--I added a createSchema customization to gatsby-node.js but now instead of null I am getting []

Answer (score 0):

> Hmm where would I include that directive?

It should be placed inside the `gatsby-node.js` inside the [`createSchemaCustomization` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/).

`@link`'s directive is the preferred way of customizing the GraphQL schema, rather than directly mapping your node inside the `gatsby-config.js`. It adds an extra security and solid customization layer but of course it also adds an extra difficulty.

Before the type declaration, you need to set the relation of the foreign-key field. Without digging more into your data structure I'm not able to know how the code should look like but it may be something like:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type MarkdownRemark implements Node {   
      frontmatter: Frontmatter 
    }  
    type Frontmatter {   
      tmdb: [tmdbAccountWatchlistMovies] @link(by: "tmdbId") 
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Double-check the `tmdbAccountWatchlistMovies` to see if the node is available as is or is nested somehow.

Comment: Thanks so much for this--I've done this, but now, instead of 'null' underneath the linked field, I am just getting [] or undefined.

Comment: It's odd because the TMDB nodes are definitely being imported, but the connection is not showing the values

Answer (score 0):

Found it--doh. The values had changed from Int to String types so just needed to wrap the IDs in apostrophes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).